# Show some html based on selected payment method

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a multistep form with 3 steps.

When the user is in the "#step2" and clicks "Go to step 3" is made an ajax request to the `storePaymentMethods()`. In this `storePaymentMethod` the `payment_method` field is validated, it needs to be required. If it is valid, that is the user selected a payment method, when the user clicks in "go to step 3" I want to show in the "#step3" div if the `payment_method` is "credit_card" some specific HTML, if is "transfers" i want to show other html.

Do you know how this can be properly achieved? How to get in the "step3" div the value of the selected payment_method in the previous step?

All the steps of the multistep form are on the same page.

```
    public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request){
           $request->validate([
                'payment_method' => 'required',
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'success'
            ], 200);


}
```

// step 2 html

```
   <form method="post" id="step2form" action="">

    <h6>Select the payment method</h6>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="transfers">
            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="mr-auto">Transfers</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="credit_card">
            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="mr-auto">Credit card</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                class="btn btn-outline-primary prev-step mr-2">
            Go back to step 2
        </button>
        <input type="submit" href="#step3" id="goToStep3"
               class="btn btn-primary float-right next-step"
               value="Go to step 3"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

// step 3 html

```
<form method="post" id="step3form" action="">
     <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="step3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
           @if($paymentMethod == "credit_card")
           //show the appropriate info for this payment method
           @else
           // show the approprate info for this payment method
           @endif
    </div>
</form>
```

// go to step 3 jquery ajax

```
var page_form_id_step2 = "step2form";

    $('#goToStep3').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id_step2);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{ route('confs.storePaymentMethods', compact('id','slug') ) }}',
            data: custom_form.serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
                nextTab($active);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#registration_form").offset().top
                }, 1000);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#registration_form").offset().top
                }, 1000);
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                var errorsHtml = '';
                $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                    errorsHtml += '<ul class="alert alert-danger mt-3"><li class="text-danger">' + value + '</li></ul>';
                    console.log(errorsHtml);
                });

                $('#step2errors').show().html(errorsHtml);
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially write everything in step3 like `<div id="credit_card_section" style="display:none;"></div>` & use `display:none` for that portion.

Then you can pass a variable related to payment method info like

```
return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'success',
                'selected_payment' => 'credit'
            ], 200);
```

At last, inside your ajax success, you can hide/show any specific portion on basis of that response data.

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                if(result['selected_payment'] == 'credit'){
                  $("#credit_card_section").show();
                }

                var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
                nextTab($active);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#registration_form").offset().top
                }, 1000);
            },
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed to " public function storePaymentMethods(Request $request){ $request->validate([  'payment_method' => 'required',]); return response()->json([  'success' => true, 'message' => 'success', 'selected_payment' => $request->payment_method,], 200); }". And in the view in the step 3 div "@if($selected_payment == "credit_card")
                                            <h1>credit card</h1>
                                        @else
     <h1>transfers</h1>
                                        @endif". But it appears "Undefined variable: selected_payment". Do you know why?

Comment: I update the question with more info to explain better the context.

Comment: you will not get that variable inside view, so that conditional block will not work properly. Rather than you can achieve it by checking that payment related data inside your success method. check my updated answer.

Comment: Remove that conditional block from your view & define your div like my suggested way(define it completely & hide it using css).

Comment: Thanks but with "success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');var result = JSON.parse(data);if(result['selected_payment'] == 'credit'){$("#credit_card_section").show(); }else{   $("#transferences_section").show();} nextTab($active); $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#registration_form").offset().top  }, 1000);},"when "go to step 2" is clicked it appears:"{success: true, message: "success", payment_method: "credit_card"}message:"success"payment_method:"credit_card"success: true"  but dont changes to the step 3 tab. Do you know why?

Comment: Even with only "var result = JSON.parse(data);" like "success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');var result = JSON.parse(data); nextTab($active);  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#registration_form").offset().top}, 1000); },"" when the user select the payment method and clicks "go to step 3" the tab dont changes to step 3.

Comment: This alert dont shows nothing "var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert(result);" but this "  var result = data.responseJSON;
                        alert(result);" shows, but it shows "undefined."

Comment: check your console, may be any silly mistake & it's returning any js error. You can also try it by commenting out all of your code & check the effect. But I think, there is something wrong with this newly added code.

Comment: Thanks, it appears on the console "VM6437:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse".

Comment: ok, then try to check your response directly without JSON parsing, I think, you can directly access it.